# How to find the probability of minimum value.

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim U[0,R]$ and we select randomly $n$ variable $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$.

Then, we can intuitively expect that there is a high probability of a point whose distance is $O(R/n)$.

How can I prove it?

Comment: Distance from what? From zero?

Comment: From zero. Thank you. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $X,X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed $U[0,R]$ random variables. We have that
\begin{align*}
P(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\le x)
&=1-P(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}>x)\\
&=1-(P(X>x))^n
\end{align*}
and
$$
P(X>x)=1-P(X\le x)=1-\frac xR=\frac{R-x}{R}
$$
for $0\le x\le R$. Hence,
$$
P(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\le x)=1-\biggl(\frac{R-x}R\biggr)^n
$$
and
$$
P(\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\le R/n)=1-\biggl(\frac{R-R/n}R\biggr)^n=1-(1-1/n)^n\to1-e^{-1}\approx0.63
$$
as $n\to\infty$.